Is NoPriceForMessageDelivery unsafe?
I've seen many instances of cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue configuring :
type PriceForSiblingDelivery = NoPriceForMessageDelivery<ParaId>;

or
type PriceForSiblingDelivery = ();

I've also seen this in many templates, and production chain code, which concerns me, is this not a denial-of-service attack vector?
